# How do I check the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{n+(-1)^n}$ for absolute convergence/conditional convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I check the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{n+(-1)^n}$ for absolute convergence/conditional convergence ?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: write the first elements of the series and use induction to test conditional convergence. For absolute convergence observe that $$\frac1{2n}\le\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}\right|$$

Comment: @Masacroso thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

for $n\geq 2$,

$$|\frac {(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}|=\frac {1}{n+(-1)^n} $$

$$\geq \frac {1}{n+1}$$

thus id doesn't converge absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\frac{1}{n+(-1)^n} \leqslant \frac{1}{n-1}$  thus $\frac{1}{n+(-1)^n}$ is a decreasing sequence that converges to $0$ and the $\sum_n(-1)^n$ is bounded thus from Dirichlet's creterion the sum converges conditionaly

Answer (score 0):

You could write out first few terms:

$a_2 = \frac{1}{3}$, $a_3 = -\frac{1}{2}$, $a_4 = \frac{1}{5}$, $a_5 = -\frac{1}{4}$ etc.

You are essentially summing $\frac{-(-1)^n}{n}$ with slightly rearranged terms. This series isn't absolutely convergent.