# Determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been really stuck on this infinite series.

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n+n}$

Trying to determine if it converges or diverges.

As far as I've got is seperating it into two partial sums (odds and evens) but even this doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you factor $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and proceed to expand the remaining expression to compare it with well-known series?

Comment: Google Leibniz Series

Comment: try to see if it converges absolutely

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That worked, thanks

Comment: Mind you what you think it worked. If you pair consecutive terms of $1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+...$ you get $0+0+0+...$. The latter converges but the former doesn't.

Comment: @arugula What I got from pairing consecutive terms is a series of which it's terms are $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and this converges via limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.
No?

Comment: The way I would do it is by applying [Abel summation, or summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test#Proof). The $(-1)^n$ is the part that gets summed, the $\frac{1}{(-1)^n+n}$ the part that gets differentiated. You cannot apply Dirichlet-Abel test directly, because $\frac{1}{(-1)^n+n}$ is not monotone, but that doesn't matter because the series $\sum|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ converges (comparing with $\sum\frac{1}{k^2}$).

Comment: @ikoikoia That is fine. But it is not enough as the example I gave above shows. You can complete it by separating the sequence of partial sums in two: the sums of even number of terms and the sum of odd number of terms. The sum of even number of terms is positive, increasing and bounded by the sum you obtained. The sum of odd number of terms is equal to a sum of an even number of terms plus an extra term. The first part converges due to your computation above, and the extra term tends to zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}$ converges or diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496386/determine-if-sum-n-2-infty-frac-1nn-1n-converges-or-diverges). Also [How do I check the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{n+(-1)^n}$ for absolute convergence/conditional convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235416/how-do-i-check-the-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac-1n-n-1n-for-abs)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the partial sums,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=2}^{2m+1} \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n+n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)
\qquad 2n \text{ and } 2n+1\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} -\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

and this sum converges
absolutely
by comparison with
$\sum \frac1{n^2}$.

To see this in
an elementary way,
starting at
$n=2$ which
does not affect convergence,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}
&\lt \sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{2n(2n-2)}\\
&= \frac14\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\\
&= \frac14\sum_{n=2}^{m} (\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac1{n})\\
&= \frac14(1-\frac1{m})\\
&\lt \frac14\\
\end{array}
$

so,
restoring $=1$,

$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}
\lt \frac16+\frac14
=\frac13
$.

Note:
Wolfy says the sum is
$1-\ln(2)
\approx 0.306852819440054690582767878541823431924499865639744745879...
$

Comment: Yes, same idea! So...

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n + n} = \sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n + n}\frac{n - (-1)^n}{n - (-1)^n} \\= \underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^nn}{n^2 - 1}}_{\text{(1)}} - \underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{1}{n^2 -1 }}_{\text{(2)}}, $$

where (1) is a convergent alternating series and (2) converges since $\frac{1}{n^2-1} \sim \frac{1}{n^2}$

Answer (score 1):

The key word is Leibnitz. But there is a small but, the sequences of the absolute values for which we build the series is *not* decreasing to zero. One can take care, and still apply Leibnitz... But ok, this is a special problem with a possible special solution, it is always good to "see the series", then maybe even more as a bonus, how quick/slow it converges/diverges...:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}
&=
\lim_{N\to\infty}
\underbrace{\sum_{2\le n\le N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}}_{\text{Notation: }a_N}
\\
&\qquad\text{ so let us consider an odd index general term $a_{2N+1}$, $N\ge 1$}
\\
a_{2N+1}
&=
\left(\frac 13-\frac 12\right) +
\left(\frac 15-\frac 14\right) +
\left(\frac 17-\frac 16\right) + \dots +
\left(\frac 1{2N+1}-\frac 1{2N}\right) 
\\
&=
-\frac 1{2\cdot 3}
-\frac 1{4\cdot 5}
-\frac 1{6\cdot 7}
-\dots-
\frac 1{2N(2N+1)}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
It is enough to consider the convergence / divergence of this subsequence, because the subsequence of even indexed terms in $(a_N)$ differs from this one by a zero sequence.

Now $(a_{2N+1})$ has negative terms, and is strictly decreasing. We show it is bounded (below), and thus the convergence. I prefer positive numbers, for instance for typographical reasons, so consider $(-a_{2N+1})$, and let us bound it as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac 1{2\cdot 3}
+\frac 1{4\cdot 5}
+\dots+
\frac 1{2N(2N+1)}
\\
&\qquad\le
\frac 1{1\cdot 3}
+\frac 1{3\cdot 5}
+\dots+
\frac 1{(2N-1)(2N+1)}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac 12\left(\frac 11-\frac 13\right) +
\frac 12\left(\frac 13-\frac 15\right) +
\dots +
\frac 12\left(\frac 1{2N-1}-\frac 1{2+N}\right)
\\
&\qquad=\frac 12\left(\frac 11-\frac 1{2+N}\right)
\\
&\qquad\longrightarrow \frac 12
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we expect that the given sequence is converging to a real number $\ge -\frac 12$.

---

Note: It is always important in such cases to see the numerical value, pari/gp gives

```
? sum(n=2, 2000001, 1.0*(-1)^n/(n+(-1)^n) )
%8 = -0.30685256944024219045776794885429218552
? sum(n=1, 1000000, 1.0/(2*n)/(2*n+1) )
%9 = 0.30685256944024219045776794885429144764
```

Comment: Yup. Same idea I had, so I upvoted you.

Comment: Also, Wolfy says the sum is 1-log(2) which agrees with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the 2 series:

(1) $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{n^2+(-1)^nn}$

(2) $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Series (1) converges absolutely (comparing with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$).

Series (2) is the Leibniz Series and converges conditionally.

Using limit laws, the series obtained by summing (1) and (2) converges as well:

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{n^2+(-1)^nn}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n(-1)^n+(-1)^{2}}{n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n+n}$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n+n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{n}\right)^{-1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

- The series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}n$ converges by Leibniz criterion
- the series $\sum O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ is convergent by comparison with Riemann series

hence  the given series is also convergent.